# Backing up and recovering data from ext4 to NTFS

Tags: backup, ntfs, ext4, fuse

On my Linux machine, I am going to do a copy for some data (files and directories) from a hard disk with an `ext4` partition to an external drive with a `fuseblk` partition, as a copy backup.

According to [this forum answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1096841): *fuseblk is just how an ntfs partition is reported via the mount command*.

Since I will copy the files from an `ext4` filesystem to a `NTFS` filesystem, and I may want to recover some info back to `ext4`, I am suspecting that I will lose some specific control information like permissions, ownership, etc... so that data won't be recover exactly as it was originally.

What specific control information will I lose?
Will the imported data take up more space that the original one?

Comment: If you save the files in a tarball, you can preserve all of the ext4 filesystem metadata.  You don't have to lose anything.

Comment: Good point @fixer1234!

Comment: Alternatively you can create a large enough NTFS file, treat it like a partition and make new ext4 filesystem inside, mount it and copy your files simply with `cp -a`.