# Oh-My-Zsh - Why did my ls colors for directories change after copying to usb?

Tags: macos, unix, colors, oh-my-zsh

I apologize if this seems like a dumb question, but I can't seem to find the answer for it anywhere.

I need to have my home directory reset on my school computer, so I copied my important files to a USB, but when I copied the USB contents back onto the computer to make sure it copied them properly, I noticed that on one of my projects, the directories show up highlighted with yellow background and black text when I use ls, as opposed to the usual light blue color they normally show up in. What does this mean? I want to make sure this isn't a problem before I let them nuke my original files from my home directory.

I am using oh-my-zsh in iTerm2 with the default theme, running OSX Sierra. I've added pictures so you can see what I'm referring to. For some reason it only does it on 1 project and I can't seem to figure out why.

Normal LS colors:

[image]

'Highlighted' directory names:

[image]

***EDIT - added `ls -la` output, `file *` output and `echo $LSCOLORS` output***

`ls -la` output:
[image]

[image]

`echo $LSCOLORS` output (same for both):
[image]

`file *` output (same for both):
[image]

Comment: It would help to see an `ls -l` and a `file *` of both directories and see how they differ. Also the output of "echo $LSCOLORS" would be nice to see.

Comment: @Spiff - I have edited the original post with those outputs, however I used `ls -la` instead of `ls -l` because the output for `ls -l` was the same, it was just in a list instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of `rwxrwxrwx` permissions set to every directory and every file in your copy. This may be because:

- the filesystem on your USB doesn't support permissions and ownership in Unix way;
- or it was mounted in a way that overrides this;
- or you copied your files and directories in a way that doesn't preserve permissions (research `cp -a …`).

Compare to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1194441/432690) and comments there. Especially:

> If you save the files in a tarball, you can preserve all of the ext4 filesystem metadata. You don't have to lose anything.

It says about `ext4` (and you probably use some other filesystem) but the situation is similar. **I think a tarball created from the original files/directories would be the best solution.**

`rwxrwxrwx` means every user can mess with these files and directories, so it's a big deal in multi-user environment. Additionally some programs (e.g. `ssh`) may refuse to work if some of their files are accessible to other users.

Comment: I try to do as much as I can using the terminal, but this time I just dragged it from it's directory onto the usb using finder. So you are saying using -a will preserve the permissions? I will try doing that first and if it doesn't work I'll just make a tarball. Thanks.